# Publify push to Heroku is rejected with invalid RUBY_VERSION

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-1.9.3, publify

I'm getting the following message when I push to Heroku:

```
Invalid RUBY_VERSION specified: Unfortunately,-a-fatal-error-has-occurred.-Please
  -see-the-Bundler-troubleshooting-documentation-at-http://bit.ly/bundler-
  issues.-Thanks!
 !     Valid versions: ruby-2.0.0, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-1.9.2, ruby-1.8.7, 
         ruby-1.9.3-jruby-1.7.0, ruby-1.8.7-jruby-1.7.0, ruby-1.9.3-jruby-1.7.1,
         ruby-1.8.7-jruby-1.7.1, ruby-1.9.3-rbx-2.0.0dev, ruby-1.8.7-rbx-2.0.0dev
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

when trying to run -> `git push heroku master`

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p385 (2013-02-06 revision 39114) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
```

in my Gemfile & Gemfile.heroku

...

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
```

Did all the [steps to troubleshoot bundler issues](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/ISSUES.md] but still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can specify your ruby version into your gem file as

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby "1.9.3"
```

and then `bundle install` locally and again push it.

Comment: Thank you :) I tried :) no luck :) maybe, cuz I have rvm. Probably, not.

Comment: Thank you again :) It was not on the top of the Gemfile :) I had some gems before source :) so that's why I think :) it didn't work :)