# Invalid Ruby Version Error While Pushing to Heroku Via Git

Tags: ruby, git, heroku

I'm having a problem not dissimilar from the problem found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298490/publify-push-to-heroku-is-rejected-with-invalid-ruby-version) However, my gemfile does have the solution that they posted, and I don't have any

I'm trying to run the command 'git push heroku master'

As a result, Heroku is giving me an error, saying:

```
Invalid ruby_version specified: there was an error in your gemfile and bundler cannot      continue. Valid versions: (list of versions)
```

Here is my gemfile where the error should be(?)

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'

require 'rubygems'
require 'mongo'
source 'http://gemcutter.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem "mongo_mapper"
gem 'pg'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

#gem 'sqlite3'


group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

I double checked my version with cmd 'ruby -v', and I was returned back 'ruby 1.9.3p392'

One of the accepted listed version was 1.9.3, so I'm not sure where heroku is seeing the conflicting/invalid versions. I've looked through many stackoverflow problems regarding this and they didn't seem to help/change the situation

Comment: Did you give us the full error message?  What is `(list of versions)`?  Is there any other output you can give us from Heroku?

Comment: Were you also using the previously used `RUBY_VERSION` method of declaring the necessary version?

Comment: What version of bundler are you using? Is it >= 1.2.0?

Comment: Bundler version : 1.3.5.

Comment: I can't copy paste from cmd, but it's a list of valid ruby versions that it expects. For example, ruby-2.0.0, ruby1.9.3 (what I have I think), ruby 1.9.2., etc.

Past that it just says "push rejected, failed to compile ruby/rails app"

master-> (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to githeroku@.com:myapp.git

Comment: @ vgoff: I'm not sure what you mean, what ruby_version method?

Comment: lines 4-6 in your Gemfile seem to be a mistake which could cause your problem (2x require, an additional source), remove them and try again.